# Impossible display categories on the catalog list

Tags: magento-2.1

Im Trying to display the **category view** in the Catalog list.

[image]

[image]
So I go to:

```
Stores ---> Attributes ---> Product
```

and edit position **category_ids**
[image]

Then I go to **Advanced Attribute Properties** and try enable "**Add to column options**".
But is not possible enable:
[image]

Its very important for me, anyone know how to solve it or enable this?